# Android Unable to create SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to create SQLite Database in my Application with this code:

```
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DB_FULL_PATH, null);
```

The `DB_FULL_PATH` is:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/app_name/databse.db";
```

The folder exists in my `My files` application.

Also, I already checked and I have these permissions in my app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When I call the create DB method I get this exeption:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database
#################################################################
Error Code : 1294 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_ENOENT)
Caused By : Specified directory or database file does not exist.
    (unknown error (code 1294): Could not open database)
#################################################################
```

Ay idea why the database is not created?

## EDIT

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 18
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    renderscriptTargetApi 22
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

I also add the build gradle file

Comment: The permissions in the manifest are not enough. Read this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java

Comment: From Android Marshmellow and higher you have to request permission externally, you can use the android default APIs but also use this cool library "Dexter" which makes it really easy: https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: @AsifRahman This is something that never happened to me with this application. I added the build gradle file for more details

Comment: @forpas This is something that never happened to me with this application. I added the build gradle file for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot open ENOENT is as it says the file or **directory** does not exist.

You can probably rely upon Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() returning an existing directory.

However you then append */**app_name**/databse.db* it is quite likely that the **app_name** directory may not exist. So you should create the directory if it doesn't exist.

For example you could use :-

```
    File dbpath = (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/app_name/databse.db"));
    if (!(new File(dbpath.getParent()).exists())) {
        new File(dbpath.getParent()).mkdirs();
    }
    myDatabase =  SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbpath,null);
```

The above does assume that you have, for [API 23+ requested permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) from the App in addition to requesting permission via the manifest.

I personally just add this class :-

```
class ExternalStoragePermissions {

    public int API_VERSION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {

            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    private ExternalStoragePermissions() {}
    // Note call this method
    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {

        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                activity,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if(permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }
}
```

and ensure that it is invoked, if required, before making such requests.

e.g. :-

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        ExternalStoragePermissions.verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    }
```

- WRITE automatically gives READ

Answer (score 0):

This might be the path you are looking for:

```
String path = this.getContext().getDatabasePath("database.db").getAbsolutePath();
```

which is something alike `/data/user/0/appname/databases/database.db`.